# Anaconda Tensorflow python

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

I'm trying to run my code in Anaconda but I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

and I don’t understand why.

Comment: is it tensorflow-gpu?

Comment: If you install python3.7 with Anaconda,you cannot use `tenserflow`.Did you install python3.7 individually?

Comment: Yes it's tensorflow-gpu and I installed anaconda without installing python 3.7